# How to get a portion of a string using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find the regex of this very simple string below.

And I've no idea how to do it.

Consider:

```
A.B.C.MSI_AlphaName
C.D.E.MSI_AlphaName_1
X.Y.Z.MSI_AlphaName_2
...
MSI_AlphaName_99
```

And so on. What would be the regex for this, given I need to extract `AlphaName`?

I have tried:

```
.+\.MSI_(.+)(?:_\d+)?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this expression:

```
MSI_([^_]+)(?:_|$)
```

The *capturing group* would match everything after the first underscore `_` all the way to the second underscore or to the end or the string, whichever comes first.

Comment: I want MSI as well as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @flippex17 You said "I need to extract `AlphaName`". Do you need `MSI` as well?

Comment: Oh well, I need MSI to be as a restriction. But I got it: [^_]+MSI_([^_]+)(?:_|$)

Comment: You can change the first `[^_]+` to just `[^_]`. You don't need a wildcard there, since you're not capturing all the characters before `MSI`, just requiring that the previous one not be underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of .+ , you will want to match on `[^_]` (the set of characters that are not `"_"`) unless you want everything after the first "_"

So your expression would look like this:

```
.+\.MSI_([^_]+)(?:_\d+)?
```